# Suppose a is a real number for which all the roots of the equation $ x^4 - 2ax^2 + x +a^2 -a =0$ are real.Find the range of values of a?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I have tried the question with $Rolle's$ theorem...
Let the equation have $2$ unequal real roots
$f'(x)= 4ax^3-4ax+1=0$
But cannot proceed after this.

Comment: Yes it can be then should we go with D>0 then find the value of a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the equation can be factorised as $(x^2 + x - a)(x^2 - x + 1 -a)$, which reduces it to the condition for two standard quadratics to have real roots.

Answer (score 4):

we can write above equation as $x^4-2ax^2+x+a^2-a=0$ as $a^2-(2x^2+1)a+x^4+x=0$

So $$\displaystyle a= \frac{(2x^2+1)\pm\sqrt{(2x^2+1)^2-4(x^4+x)}}{2}=\frac{(2x^2+1)\pm (2x-1)}{2}$$

So $x^2+x-a=0$ or $x^2-x+1-a=0$

So for real roots , $1+4a\geq 0$ and  $1-4(1-a)\geq 0 $